# Is there any method to get all the offsets of a session container in zend framework 2.?

Tags: zend-framework2, zend-session

when I go through the documentation of zend framework 2, i just found methods like 
    `getOffset($key)` and `offsetExists($key)`. But for both we have to specify the keys.
My question is, Is there any method or any other way for retrieving all the keys or all the data associated with a container without specifying the keys.

Answer (score 1):

The container is just an ArrayObject and implements getIterator, so you can simply do

```
foreach ($container as $key => $value)
{
    var_dump($key);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option without a loop is to get keys or values from `getArrayCopy()`

```
$values = $container->getArrayCopy();
var_dump($values);

$keys = array_keys($values);
var_dump($keys);
```